# Change variation price when custom selection is made

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce variable product outside of loop and not on single product page, I want to change variation price based on the selection of a form. If an area is selected change variation price with the custom price added in the custom field created for that variation(area1 or area2). My code works for displaying the correct price after selection but when I add the variation to cart the default price of the variation is added to cart not the custom price.

```html
<form class="areas-form" method="POST" action="">
    Select Your Area 
    <select name="area" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="" disabled selected>--select--</option>
        <option value="area1">Area 1</option>
        <option value="area2">Area 2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'varient_price', 99, 2 ); // this code is added in functions.php

function varient_price($price, $variation){
if (  $variation->product_type == 'variation'  ) {
      if(isset($_POST["area"])){
       $area=$_POST["area"];
      } 
    $price = get_post_meta( $variation->variation_id, $area.'_price',true);
    
        return $price;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question comment, rest display and other things you are managing.
Here, I have just attached the woocommerce hooks and calculation to get your area price to set in your selected variation.

**Firstly, you need to get the dynamic price in your select option as per area wise.**

**Secondly, below code will help you to set your parameter request to be add into cart meta:**

```
function add_area_data_cart_meta( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
     
    if( isset( $_POST['area'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data[ "area" ] = $_POST['area'];     
    }

    
    return $cart_item_data;
     
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_area_data_cart_meta', 99, 2 );
```

**Third, before product get add to cart. The above code will fetch your area price value which we have added using above code and below code will set your area price as new price in the cart.**

```
function calculate_area_price_as_variation_price( $cart_object ) {
    if( !WC()->session->__isset( "reload_checkout" )) {
        /* Gift wrap price */
        $additionalPrice = 100;
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
            if( isset( $value["area"] ) ) {                
                if( method_exists( $value['data'], "set_price" ) ) {
                                        /* Woocommerce 3.0 + */
                    $value['data']->set_price( $value["area"] );
                } else {
                        /* Version before 3.0 */
                    $value['data']->price = ( $value["area"] );                    
                }           
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'calculate_area_price_as_variation_price', 99 );
```

Please let me know if you find any issues.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but the above code did not changed anything

Comment: Did you set value as custom price in custom area dropdown?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, the problem I think is on the add to cart button, is still getting the default variation price, not changing with the area price

Comment: Your select drop down should be like this

Comment: <select name="area" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="" disabled selected>--select--</option>
        <option value="50">Area 1</option>
        <option value="60">Area 2</option>
    </select>

Comment: You can replace 50/60 by your custom price. 50/60 is just an example

Comment: If I replace value="price" my select will not work anymore, because the custom fields for variations are area1, area2 etc, area1 has price 50, area2 has price 60, so with value="area1", value="area2" etc. when I select Area 1, on page frefresh my filter woocommerce_product_variation_get_price does the job and each variation that has area1 custom field price is changed and displayed correctly with that one, I can see it bellow the selected options, the only problem is when Im adding this to cart, the default price of the variation is added

Comment: I have multiple attributes, like Length, Weight, Size and created variations for all, so I did not want to add another attribute Area (they are like 5 areas) because I will have too many variations over 1500, so I created custom fields for each existing variation area1, area2 etc. with custom price

Comment: Just put select name value as area and option can be multiple not an issue.

Comment: Yes, but with <option value="price_area_1">Area 1</option>, my select is not working anymore only with <option value="area1">Area 1</option>